# Prevent wrong values inside custom type upon fmap

Tags: haskell

I'd like to have a monoid of a 12 hours clock.

```
data Clock12Hours = Clock12Hours Int
    deriving (Show)

instance Monoid Clock12Hours where
    mappend (Clock12Hours x) (Clock12Hours y) = Clock12Hours $ (x + y) `mod` 12
    mempty = Clock12Hours 12
```

when I `mappend (Clock12Hours 4) (Clock12Hours 10)` I get correct value - `Clock12Hours 2`.

My questions are:

1. When I `fmap (id) Clock12Hours 10`, I get `Clock12Hours 10`. But how did it know how to fmap, if I haven't provided a functor definition (which as clarified in the comments, can't even be done)?
2. When I try to `fmap (+1) (Clock12Hours 10)` I get an error `No instance for (Num Clock12Hours) arising from a use of ‘+’` - why is that?
3. My goal here is that if I would try to fmap some Int operation, it will give a result similar to the monoid (e.g. `fmap (+4) (Clock12Hours 10)` would return `Clock12Hours 2`. How?

Comment: This type is not a Functor and cannot become a Functor. A Functor needs to be a type constructor that takes 1 parameter.

Comment: Oh yeah, I got that it can't since it doesn't have a parameter, but still the 3 question form above are not clear to me.

Comment: GHC version 7.10.3 throws an error on `fmap id (Clock12Hours 10)`.

Comment: The three questions are meaningless: you do not and cannot have a functor, so I don't believe the results you claim for #1 and #2. Question 3, ignoring the functor issue, would only require a `Num` instance for `Clock12Hours`, since `(+4) :: Num a => a -> a`.

Comment: @chepner why would I make up the results? :) They are what I got when I try them on `ghci version 7.10.3`. I will remove the word "Functors" from the post, but my requirements/ questions still remain on how to achieve the functionality + how come `fmap id` worked

Comment: @amitaibu Check again `fmap id (Clock12Hours 10)`. It looks impossible to us that it is producing any result. Maybe, post the full code and the GHCi session. Possibly, something is defined differently from what was posted above.

Comment: Indeed, sorry - the code I tried was `fmap (id) Clock12Hours 12` (and it works). I'll update the post

Comment: @amitaibu: Function application is left-associative in Haskell, so that code means `(fmap id Clock12Hours) 12`. This "works" because the `Clock12Hours` data constructor acts like a function, so your code uses `instance Functor ((->) r)` (see https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-637 ).
I think you meant to write `fmap id (Clock12Hours 12)`, which does not work because `(Clock12Hours 12)` is not any kind of `Functor`.

Comment: Thanks @jeson, now I understand where my confusion came from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant to do something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Safe #-}
module Numeric.IntMod12 (
    IntMod12(), lift1Enum, lift2Enum
) where

newtype IntMod12 = IntMod12 Int deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

instance Enum IntMod12 where
    {-# INLINABLE toEnum #-}
    toEnum i = IntMod12 (mod i 12)
    {-# INLINABLE fromEnum #-}
    fromEnum (IntMod12 i) = i

lift1Enum :: (Enum a, Enum b) => (Int -> Int) -> a -> b
{-# INLINABLE lift1Enum #-}
lift1Enum f = \ x -> toEnum (f (fromEnum x))

lift2Enum :: (Enum a, Enum b, Enum c) => (Int -> Int -> Int) -> a -> b -> c
{-# INLINABLE lift2Enum #-}
lift2Enum f = \ x y -> toEnum (f (fromEnum x) (fromEnum y))

instance Real IntMod12 where
    {-# INLINABLE toRational #-}
    toRational (IntMod12 i) = toRational i

instance Num IntMod12 where
    {-# INLINABLE fromInteger #-}
    fromInteger i = IntMod12 (fromInteger (mod i 12))
    (+) = lift2Enum (+)
    (-) = lift2Enum (-)
    (*) = lift2Enum (*)
    negate = lift1Enum negate
    abs = id
    signum 0 = 0
    signum _ = 1

instance Integral IntMod12 where
    {-# INLINABLE toInteger #-}
    toInteger (IntMod12 i) = toInteger i
    div = lift2Enum div
    mod = lift2Enum mod
    quot = lift2Enum quot
    rem = lift2Enum rem
    divMod x y = (toEnum d, toEnum m) where
        (d, m) = divMod (fromEnum x) (fromEnum y)
    quotRem x y = (toEnum q, toEnum r) where
        (q, r) = quotRem (fromEnum x) (fromEnum y)

instance Monoid IntMod12 where
    mempty = 0
    mappend = (+)
```

Because this is not a `Functor` (and cannot be turned into a `Functor`), you would have to use something like `lift1Enum` instead of `fmap`.

Answer (score 0):

I have no answer for `1.` because I can't reproduce the error on GHC 7.10.3.

For `2.`: Only types which take 1 type parameter to construct can be functors because `fmap` is *polymorphic* in its arguments, while `Clock12Hours` is not.

To answer `3.`: Well a map operation unpacks it's argument, applys a function and re-packs the whole thing. Using this definition, we come up with:

```
myMap :: (Int -> Int) -> Clock12Hours -> Clock12Hours
myMap f (Clock12Hours time) = Clock12Hours (f time)
```

But now we have the problem that we might not get a 12 hour time, so we have two options: add 0 (`mappend mempty`), or write a `normalize` function:

```
normalize (Clock12Hours x) = Clock12Hours (x `mod` 12)
normalize clock = myMap (`mod` 12) clock
normalize = myMap (`mod` 12)
```

Comment: So, on your installation the `fmap id` doen't work at-all? (which makes more sense to me, because I don't understand how it works on mine). I seem to also have v7.10.3.

Could I change my `data` to something else to accomplish my needs, but still have the argument only Int (i.e. `data Clock12Hours a = Clock12Hours a` won't limit it to `Int` only)?

Comment: @amitaibu You could do that, although that would defeat the purpose of your datatype, no? You cannot make your type polymorphic and restrict it afterward, that is nonsensical. Also, that would be the [`Identity` functor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html), which already exists in Haskell. **TL;DR** Don't do that.